# Applescript variable returns right value but evaluates wrong

Tags: applescript

Here's a simple script that should return "task type." When I run the script and then ask it to return the variable, it returns "task type". But when I run the script and ask if the variable contains "task," it returns "false." What am I doing wrong?

**Script**

```
tell application "TaskPaper"
    tell front document
        set WhatType to get entry type of selected entry
    end tell
end tell
```

**When followed with**

```
TaskPaper
```

returns "task type". So far, so good!

**But when followed with**

```
WhatType contains "task"
```

returns "false". I'm confused about how this is possible.

Comment: The "type/s" are probably not strings - try it like this: "if WhatType is task type ..."

Comment: Thanks, @DigiMonk. You're right. I accepted jweaks's answer since that solved my problem, but I appreciate your clarification, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include your full code, btw, for better help.
It fails because you're comparing a string "task" to a task type (which is not a string class).
You're comparing items of different types.

You can either compare:

```
if WhatType is task type then
```

or you can try to coerce to a string:

```
if (WhatType as string) contains "task" then
```

Comment: Thanks, @jweaks. The first one didn't work (AppleScript told me that "talk type" was not defined.) But the second one works just fine. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it's working. The first one (checking the type) will work, just gotta get the syntax right. Perhaps:  if WhatType is entry type task, then  ... or if WhatType is task, then... or  if entry type of WhatType is task, then... etc.  To check stuff like that, put in a: get properties of to look at the syntax.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I'll try to test it and report back eventually.

Comment: I got it with "if entry type of WhatType is task type." Thanks again for your help.

Comment: excellent.  viewing the Applescript Dictionary of TaskPaper will give help in figuring it out, though it can be tough to discern an app's syntax. The publisher needs to make example scripts available.